# Displaying playlist data from YouTube API v3

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the YouTube v3 API to show all the videos from a particular YouTube playlist. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$playlistId = 'PLHGPqm6HHcedxhoMXo9m9yKqsOmOB_S0F';
$maxResults = 20;
$apiKey = 'APIKEYHERE';

$string = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId='.$playlistId.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$apiKey.''));

foreach($string['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['title'];
}
?>
```

I have used Postman to test the url and it is definitely getting data but when i try to echo any data it isn't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learnt that Json decode will return stdclass by default json_decode php.net so you would have to replace foreach with this:

```
foreach($string->items as $item) {
    echo $item->snippet->title;
}
```